# $A$ is closed $\implies X/A$ is Hausdorff whenever $X$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space. If $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ then $X/A$ is Hausdorff.

Let $\{x\},\{y\} \in X/A$ such that $x,y \in X \setminus A$ with $x \neq y.$ Then since $X \setminus A$ is open in $X$ and since any subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff there exist open neighbourhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively in $X$ such that $U_x, U_y \subseteq X \setminus A$ and $U_x \cap U_y = \varnothing.$ But then $U_x$ and $U_y$ are saturated open subsets of $X$ with respect to $p.$ So $p(U_x)$ and $p(U_y)$ together gives a separation of $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ in $X/A.$

Now if I take $x \in X \setminus A$ then how do I separate $\{x\}$ and $A$ in $X/A\ $? Inspite of my tireless effort I am unable to show that. Would anybody please give me some suggestion which enables me to prove the rest of the result?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT** $:$ Here $p : X \longrightarrow X/A$ is the quotient map.

Comment: This statement is false. In $\Bbb R_K$ take $A=K$ and the quotient is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work if $X$ is, additionally, regular. Seperating the point $A$ from $\{x\}$ in $X/A$ is essentially the same as seperating the closed subset $A$ from the point $x$ in $X$, but this is not implied by the Hausdorff property - it is called regularity.

To understand this, let's think about what an open neighborhood of $A$ looks like in $X/A$. By definition, a neighborhood $A \in U \subseteq X/A$ is open iff $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$. The preimage of $\{A\}$ is $A$, and the preimage of any other point $\{x\}$ is just $\{x\}$. So taking the preimage of our neighborhood $U$ has the effect of replacing the point $A \in X/A$ with the subset $A \subseteq X$. Thus, open neighborhoods of $A$ in $X/A$ are precisely those subsets which pull back to open subsets of $X$ containing $A$.

Now, suppose indeed that we could find disjoint open neighborhoods $A \in U$ and $\{x\} \in V$. Then we'd have $A \subseteq p^{-1}[U]$ and $x \in p^{-1}[V]$. But then these preimages are disjoint open subsets of $X$ which separate the subset $A$ from the point $x$. Thus, if the proposition you wrote was true then $X$ would have to be regular. Unfortunately, not all Hausdorff spaces are regular. See [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_not_implies_regular) for an example.

Comment: In the third paragraph disjointness of $p^{-1} [U]$ and $p^{-1} [V]$ doesn't necessarily imply regularity of the underlying topological space. It may so happen that there exists a non-regular Hausdorff space $X$ in which there exist separations of a specific closed subset $A$ from points not contained in $A.$ For regularity the same phenomenon has to be true for every closed subset. Am I right?

Comment: Although it is clear that regularity of the entire space $X$ guarantees Hausdorffness of $X/A$ whenever $A$ is closed.

Comment: Yes that is right, a seperation of the points $A, \{x\}$ in $X/A$ is the same as a seperation of the closed subset $A$ and the point $x$ within $X$. A nonregular space can certainly have specific closed subsets that seperate from specific points, and it may happen that all points can be seperated from a fixed $A$ in a nonregular space, in which case $X/A$ for that specific $A$ will be Hausdorff. By the way, if $A$ is compact this is true without any regularity condition, as in a Hausdorff space, you can always seperate disjoint compact sets.

Comment: That's exactly right, the quotient is not Hausdorff. I linked that example because it was an example of a closed set that cannot be separated from a point in a Hausdorff space, which is precisely the sort of counterexample we needed to falsify your proposition.

Comment: Is $\Bbb R_K/K$ Hausdorff? I think we cannot separate $\{0\}$ and $K$ there. Because any open subset containing $0$ which is contained in $\Bbb R_K \setminus K$ and any open subset containing $K$ in $\Bbb R_K$ are saturated with respect to the quotient map $p : X \longrightarrow X/A$ and hence $\{0\}$ and $K$ can only be separated in $\Bbb R_K/K$ if and only if $0$ and $K$ can be separated by disjoint open subsets in $\Bbb R_K,$ which is not true (That is the way we show that $\Bbb R_K$ is not regular).